# Property 'name' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to fix Property 'name' does not exist on type ?

code block :

```
**Environemnt.prod.ts**

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  name:"(Production)",

  apiUrl: 'https://test.org/getstatusboardvalue',
  client_id: '4951-b5a3-0b4a94976aea',
  client_secret: '7147f6b98f41',
  scope: 'cis',
  auth: '',
};

**app.component.ts**

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  envName = environment.name;
  public maintenanceMode: boolean = false;
  public scaleLevel = ScaleLevel.Normal;

  public get clientBoardTable(): BoardTable {
    return this._appService.clientBoardTable;
  }

**app.component.html**
<div [ngClass]="{'overlay': maintenanceMode}"></div>
<div [ngClass]="{'smaller': scaleLevel == 1, 'smallest': scaleLevel == 2}" class="main">
    <div>
        Environemnt<b style="color: red" >{{envName}}</b>
    </div>
  <div class="page-contents">


    <board-table [source]="clientBoardTable"></board-table>
  </div>
  <div class="page-footer">Data as of: {{clientBoardTable.lastUpdatedOn | date:'medium'}}</div> 

</div>
<notification-list></notification-list>
```

How to get the expected result like below
Expected result : Environment = QA 
or
Environment = PRODUCTION

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(17,25): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; apiUrl: string; auth: string; client_id: string; client_secret: string; scope: string; }'.

Comment: How are you importing Environemnt.prod.ts in app.component.ts?

Comment: Which is line 17 now?

Comment: according to your error, `name` doesn't exist on your type. So seems like a correct error ;)

Comment: @AJT_82: Its does. The const `environment` does have a property `name`.

Comment: Unless OP has made a typo somwhere it should work.

Comment: @NicholasK Yeah, the const seems to have it... but the error refers to a type. There must be something going on that we are not seeing?

Comment: If you just want to display PRODUCTION, can you define environment as
`environment = {..,name:'PRODUCTION',... }`
I don't see the point of "" and ()

Comment: Make sure you have the same JSON structure in environment.ts as well

Comment: Change `import environment from ...` to `import { environment } from ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected.after clean the cache i rebuild it and it is working fine as expected.